# Theoretical: method_missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just started to learn Rails and I cannot understand that:

In my Post controller I do not have method show (not described), but I put in my controller that:

```
def method_missing(name, *args)
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

I think that if controller couldn't find action show - it would call `method_missing` and after that redirect to `index` method, but Rails tries to render view `show.html.erb`.

Why is method missing not catching? How can I use `method_missing`?

Comment: `not described` means? can you please post your PostsController too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails does not require action to be present in controller if corresponding template exists. It just assumes empty action and renders template, that is why your `method_missing` isn't invoked.

If you don't need `show` action anyway - just remove `show.html.erb` and `method_missing` will work as expected.

Comment: but in wich case controller can call method_missing ?

Comment: @DemitriyDN when there is no template to render.